# Express.js checking request type with .is() doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to check what the type of content is, but it doesn't appear to be working. Here is the output on the shell:

```
$ node app.js
# Request http://localhost:3000 via browser
CLIENT DOES NOT WANT XML, JSON, OR HTML
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

And here is the contents of the app.js script:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.is('xml')) {
        console.log("CLIENT WANTS XML");
    } else if (req.is('json') || req.is('html')) {
        console.log("CLIENT WANTS JSON OR HTML");
    } else {
        console.log("CLIENT DOES NOT WANT XML, JSON, OR HTML");
        console.log(req.header('Accept'));
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I would expect the `text/html` Accept header to trigger the `req.is('html')` function or even the `application/xhtml+xml` Accept header to trigger the `req.is('xml')`, but the `else` statement actually gets run. I'm using Express 3.0.0 rc1 and Node 0.8.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I should be using `.accepts()`, instead of `.is()`.