# NodeJS : Validating request type (checking for JSON or HTML)

Tags: json, node.js, express

I would like to check if the type that is requested by my client is JSON or HTML, as I want my route to satisfy both human and machine needs.

I have read the Express 3 documentation at:

> http://expressjs.com/api.html

And there are two methods `req.accepts()` and `req.is()`, used like this:

```
req.accepts('json')
```

or

```
req.accepts('html')
```

Since these are not working as they should, I tried using:

```
var requestType = req.get('content-type');
```

or

```
var requestType = req.get('Content-Type');
```

`requestType` is always `undefined`...

Using the suggestion at this thread:

> [Express.js checking request type with .is() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727836/express-js-checking-request-type-with-is-doesnt-work)

does not work either. what am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit 1**: I have checked for correct client HTML negotiation. Here  are my two different request headers (taken from the debugger inspector):

> HTML : `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`
>
> JSON : `Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`

---

**Solution** (thanks to Bret):

Turns out I was specifying the Accept headers wrong, and the `*/*` was the issue. Here is the code that works!

```
//server (now works)
var acceptsHTML = req.accepts('html');
var acceptsJSON = req.accepts('json');

if(acceptsHTML)  //will be null if the client does not accept html
{}
```

I am using JSTREE, a jQuery plugin that uses jQuery Ajax calls underneath). The parameters passed to the Ajax call are in the "ajax" field, and I have replaced the "accepts" parameter with a complete "headers" object. Now it works, and should solve the problem when you are using plain jQuery if it should ever occur.

```
//client 

.jstree({
            // List of active plugins
            "plugins" : [
                "themes","json_data","ui","crrm","cookies","dnd","search","types","hotkeys","contextmenu"
            ],

            "json_data" : {
                "ajax" : {
                    // the URL to fetch the data
                    "url" : function(n) {
                        var url = n.attr ? IDMapper.convertIdToPath(n.attr("id")) : "<%= locals.request.protocol + "://" + locals.request.get('host') + locals.request.url %>";
                        return url;
                    },
                    headers : {
                        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`var requestType = req.get('Content-Type');` definitely works if a content-type was actually specified in the request (I just re-verified this a minute ago). If no content-type is defined, it will be undefined. Keep in mind that typically only POST and PUT requests will specify a content type. Other requests (like GET) will often specify a list of accepted types, but that's obviously not the same thing.

EDIT:

Okay, I understand your question better now. You're talking about the Accept: header, not content-type.

Here's what's happening: notice the `*/*;q=0.8` at the end of listed accept types? That essentially says "I'll accept anything." Therefore, `req.accepts('json')` is always going to return `"json"` because technically it's an accepted content type.

I think what you want is to see if `application/json` is explicitly listed, and if so, respond in json, otherwise respond in html. This can be done a couple of ways:

```
// a normal loop could also be used in place of array.some()
if(req.accepted.some(function(type) {return type.value === 'application/json';}){
    //respond json
} else {
    //respond in html
}
```

or using a simple regular expression:

```
if(/application\/json;/.test(req.get('accept'))) {
    //respond json
} else {
    //respond in html
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I am making a GET request; I could simply compare the full content of the header with a hard coded string, but that is not clean. I have posted the extracts from the debugger for both requests at the end of the question.

Comment: @JoãoRochadaSilva hopefully you got the problem figured out. If not, I think the edit to my answer will solve it.

Comment: Thanks, that subtle `*/*` Accept header was the problem! Thank you so much, I will post the final code that works!

Comment: Your regexp should be "/application\/json/" without the ";". The charset is not always sent after application/json content type (ex with POSTMAN). When its not, there is no ";" after the string "application/json".

Answer (score 14):

According to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.accepts), this the proper solution

```
req.accepts(['html', 'json']) === 'json'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had to pass `req.accepts(['html', 'json']) === 'json'`

Comment: This is by far the best solution to this problem.

Comment: Above answer did not work when I sent `content-type:json` using postman. This answer is working though - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018920/2488801

Answer (score 3):

Please define "*not working as they should*", because they do for me.

In other words:

```
// server.js
console.log('Accepts JSON?', req.accepts('json') !== undefined);

// client sends 'Accept: application/json ...', result is:
Accepts JSON? true

// client sends 'Accept: something/else', result is:
Accepts JSON? false
```

The `Content-Type` header as sent by a client isn't used for content negotiation, but to declare the content type for any body data (like with a `POST` request). Which is the reason why `req.is()` isn't the correct method to call in your case, because that checks `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 0):

To throw my hat in the ring, I wanted easily readable routes without having `.json` suffixes everywhere or having to have each route hide these details in the handler.

```
router.get("/foo", HTML_ACCEPTED, (req, res) => res.send("<html><h1>baz</h1><p>qux</p></html>"))
router.get("/foo", JSON_ACCEPTED, (req, res) => res.json({foo: "bar"}))
```

Here's how those middlewares work.

```
function HTML_ACCEPTED (req, res, next) { return req.accepts("html") ? next() : next("route") }
function JSON_ACCEPTED (req, res, next) { return req.accepts("json") ? next() : next("route") }
```

Personally I think this is quite readable (and therefore maintainable).

```
$ curl localhost:5000/foo --header "Accept: text/html"
<html><h1>baz</h1><p>qux</p></html>

$ curl localhost:5000/foo --header "Accept: application/json"
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Notes:

- I recommend putting the HTML routes before the JSON routes because some browsers will accept HTML *or* JSON, so they'll get whichever route is listed first. I'd expect API users to be capable of understanding and setting the Accept header, but I wouldn't expect that of browser users, so browsers get preference.
- The [last paragraph](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application) in ExpressJS Guide talks about next('route'). In short, next() skips to the next middleware in the same route while next('route') bails out of this route and tries the next one.
- Here's the reference on [req.accepts](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.accepts).