# How do I check Content-Type using ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a pretty basic RESTful API so far, and my Express app is configured like so:

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.post('/api/vehicles', vehicles.addVehicle);
```

How/where can I add middleware that stops a request from reaching my `app.post` and `app.get` if the content type is not `application/json`?

The middleware should only stop a request with improper content-type to a url that begins with `/api/`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you're using Express 4.0 or higher, you can call [`request.is()`](http://expressjs.com/tr/api.html#req.is) on requests from your handlers to filter request content type. For example:

```
app.use('/api/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.is('application/json')) {
        // Send error here
        res.send(400);
    } else {
        // Do logic here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 32):

This mounts the middleware at `/api/` (as a prefix) and checks the content type:

```
app.use('/api/', function(req, res, next) {
  var contype = req.headers['content-type'];
  if (!contype || contype.indexOf('application/json') !== 0)
    return res.send(400);
  next();
});
```

Comment: I think it should be: contype.indexOf('application/json') !== 1, as indexOf returns -1 in case of not found, 0 is a valid element and it's the first one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the `contype.indexOf()` here is searching a string and ensuring it starts with `'application/json'`. If it doesn't exist at the beginning of the string, it's some other content type (even something like `'foo/x-bar-baz; blah=application/json'`).

Comment: Ah I see, I was under the impression that in order to access multiple content-type directives `req.headers['content-type']` would return an array itself, so you would just search if `'application/json'` is at any index of that array with `!== -1`.

Answer (score 4):

Get content type from the request by using this.

```
req.get('Content-Type')
```

Example :

```
app.post("/api/test", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Request type :", req.get('Content-Type'));
    //your code
})
```

Comment: Just wanted to add this can return `undefined` is it's not set.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the `express-ensure-ctype` middleware:

```js
const express = require('express');
const ensureCtype = require('express-ensure-ctype');

const ensureJson = ensureCtype('json');
const app = express();

app.post('/', ensureJson, function (req, res) {
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this express middleware will validate all PATCH, POST and PUT and ensure that they contain the `application/json` header:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (['PATCH', 'POST', 'PUT'].includes(req.method) && !req.is('application/json')) {
        res.send(400);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Limiting it to certain methods will prevent errors with other methods such as GET

Answer (score 0):

For input validation a good module is [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator). It provides the middlewares needed to do any kind of check. In your case something like:

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
app.use('/api/', [
   check('content-type').equals('application/json')
 ], function(req, res, next) {
   const errors = validationResult(req);
   if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
     return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
   }
   next();
});
```

Comment: Looks much more cumbersome than `request.is()`