# node.js express: How can I know if a request is an AJAX request?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

Let's say I have a small piece of code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  //I want to acccess 'req' and get info whether it's an AJAX call
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I go inside the app.get(..) function, I want to know if the get request sent is an AJAX call. What is the field in the object 'req' that can tell me this?

Comment: var isAjax = req.xhr;

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902293/nodejs-validating-request-type-checking-for-json-or-html

Comment: Just add a parameter when requesting XHR.

Comment: By the way, do you have a link that gives information about all fields of req object in express?

Comment: Check this: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req

Comment: thanks. it's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  //I want to acccess 'req' and get info whether it's an AJAX call
  if(req.xhr){
     //the request is ajax call
  }
})
```

Comment: @lonesomeday in that case you have to set the header manually `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` which will work.

Comment: @SumanKandu Or other, more suitable methods, like the `Accepts` header.

Answer (score 10):

The header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` HTTP header is not automatically added to an AJAX request, either with `fetch` or with the old-fashioned use of the `XMLHttpRequest` object. It is often added by client libraries such as jQuery.

If the header is present, it is represented in Express by `request.xhr`.

If you want to add it to the request (the simplest solution to this problem) you can add it as a custom header with `fetch`:

```
fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
});
```

This will now be reflected in `req.xhr`.

A *better* solution is to set the `Accept` header to a sensible value. If you want JSON to be returned, set `Accept` to `application/json`:

```
fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
});
```

You can then test for this with `req.accepts`:

```
switch (req.accepts(['html', 'json'])) { //possible response types, in order of preference
    case 'html':
        // respond with HTML
        break;
    case 'json':
        // respond with JSON
        break;
    default:
        // if the application requested something we can't support
        res.status(400).send('Bad Request');
        return;
}
```

This is much more powerful than the `req.xhr` approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var isAjax = req.xhr;
});

app.listen(3000);
```