# mobile and web api error case in nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, api

I need to develop an API for web as well as mobile with NodeJS as backend. Since, both have common endpoints --> I was wondering how to handle error cases like for e.g. --> if there is an error and user is on web I can do res.redirect and the user will be redirected whereas if the request was from mobile then I will have to set an 'action' variable which will guide the mobile app to take the next action for e.g. ask the user to login again.

```
app.get('/users/musicList', function(req, res){

 // check with db. 
 // lets say there is some error --> the API token is not valid so user needs to 
// login

 if (req was from web) {
     res.redirect('/signin');
 } else {
    var result = {action  : 'SIGNIN'};
    res.status(200).json(result);
 }


});
```

Is this the correct way to go ? It makes code look a bit messy.  Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

An Easy way to do this is to have two different endpoints for mobile and web. (Wait I have two more solution).But this would result in code duplication.

```
web: domain/route
mobile: domain/api/route
```

Another way is to have only api/route which uses only `json`. And to handle the error and routing in front end. This works if you are using front-end frameworks like angular and using AJAX requests.

Third one is to check for the client need and acting as in your question. Check this link for how to determine what client needs.
[NodeJS : Validating request type (checking for JSON or HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902293/nodejs-validating-request-type-checking-for-json-or-html)

Comment: Yeah I think I will go with the second approach. Have same code and handle the cases in front-end